# Moving Sqoop data from HDFS to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

When importing a bunch of large MySQL tables into HDFS using Sqoop, I forgot to include the --hive-import flag.  So now I've got these tables sitting in HDFS, and am wondering if there's an easy way to load the data into Hive (without writing the LOAD DATA statements myself).

I tried using sqoop create-hive-table:

```
./bin/sqoop create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/dw --username xxx --password xxx --hive-import --table tweets
```

While this did create the correct hive table, it didn't import any data into it.  I have a feeling I'm missing something simple here...

For the record, I am using Elastic MapReduce, with Sqoop 1.4.1.

Comment: From digging around in the Sqoop source code, I'm pretty sure this isn't possible with within Sqoop.  However, if it were possible, it looks like all Sqoop would do is execute something like "LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hadoop/tweets' INTO TABLE `tweets`" in Hive.  I guess that's painless enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you create an external table in hive and point it to these files?

```
create external table something(a string, b string) location 'hdfs:///some/path'
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify "import" in your command.  Syntax is sqoop tool-name [tool-arguments]

It should look like this:

> $ sqoop **import** --create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/dw --username xxx --password xxx --hive-import --table tweets